# Getting the authors whose posts liked most with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically i have 3 tables, Users, Posts, Actions (actions are likes). Users can like each others posts. I want to fetch the top 10 authors who had their posts liked most in last 7 days. My query is like below and it works, but i doubt if my query is efficient really. Can it be optimized to perform better?

**Query:**

```
SELECT u.*, COUNT(a.post_id) as likes
FROM Actions AS a
LEFT JOIN Posts p ON p.id = a.post_id
LEFT JOIN Users AS u ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE a.dateCreated >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY likes DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**Users**

[image]

**Posts**

[image]

**Actions**

[image]

Comment: It is very simple and straight forward query. I don't think any further optimization in this query **EXCEPT** make sure you have created indexes and select only those columns are required instead of using astrick

Comment: The query looks ok. Why are you using `LEFT JOINs` though? Every action is related to a post, which must exist in the post table. Every post is made by a user, which must exist in the user table. Also, just for consistency sake, you alias the actions and users table using `AS u`, but you lack `AS` with posts. Nothing major, just to be consistent.

Comment: @Ravi i am already using the necessary ones, just to keep it short here i used * . Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SchmitzIT Joining left is more kind of a habit for me i guess :) just to make sure. Oh yeah, somehow i've missed that. Thanks a bunch mate.

Comment: @Elnoor that's a bad habit ;) Use it where appropriate (I.e. you need to see all customers, even if they did not place an order).

Comment: i see your point. Yeah i am a bit bad with all those joins, should spend some time to really go through them. I modified my query now, to use JOIN. Thanks for advice :)